# Large dataset with many weights causing an extremely slow training process with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, large-data, large-files

I have a background in biology and am currently experimenting and learning machine learning to train a microarray dataset I have that consists of 140 cell lines with 54871 gene expressions of each cell line. Essentially, I have 140 rows, each row is comprised of 54871 columns representing a value that is a gene expression level of that cell line. Basically, a 140*54871 matrix. Within the 140 cell lines, I have labeled each row(cell line) as either group 1 or group 2 for my code to learn to discern and predict if I were to input a 1*54871 matrix, which group it would belongs to.

I have divided the dataset in two parts for training and testing. My question comes: since I have 54871 weights for each gene expression, my training is extremely slow as in every 1000 iterations, my cost function (mean squared error) only goes from 0.3057 to 0.3047 and this would take around 2-3 minutes. Also, as the iteration increase you can see that it kind of plateaus making it seems like it would take forever to train until the model has a cost function of even >=0.1. I left it overnight waking up with a mse value of 0.3014 when it began with a 0.3103.

Is there anything I can do to speed up the training process? Or is there something I am doing wrong. Thanks!

This is my code, sorry if it is a little messy:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy

# download csv data sheet of all cell lines
input_data = pd.read_csv(
    'C:/Users/lalalalalalala.csv',
    index_col=[0, 1],
    header=0,
    na_values='---')
matrix_data = input_data.as_matrix()

# user define cell lines of interest for supervised training
group1 = input(
    "Please enter cell lines that makes up the your cluster of interest with spaces in between(case sensitive):")
group_split1 = group1.split(sep=" ")

# assign label of each: input cluster = 1
#                      rest of cluster = 0
# extract data of input group
# split training and test set
# all these if else statement represents split when the input group1 is not a even number
split = len(group_split1)
g1_train = input_data.loc[:, group_split1[0:int(split / 2) if len(group_split1) % 2 == 0 else (int(split / 2) + 1)]]
g1_test = input_data.loc[:,
          group_split1[(int(split / 2) if len(group_split1) % 2 == 0 else (int(split / 2) + 1)):split]]
g2 = input_data.loc[:, [x for x in list(input_data) if x not in group_split1]]
split2 = g2.shape[1]
g2_train = g2.iloc[:, 0:int(split2 / 2) if len(group_split1) % 2 == 0 else (int(split2 / 2) + 1)]
g2_test = g2.iloc[:, (int(split2 / 2) if len(group_split1) % 2 == 0 else (int(split2 / 2) + 1)):split2]

# amplify the input data if the input data is too small:
amp1 = (int((g2_train.shape[1] - split) / int(split / 2))) if g2_train.shape[
                                                                  1] >= split else 1  # if g1 is less than g2 amplify
g1_train = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.tile(g1_train, (1, amp1)), index=g2_train.index)
amp2 = (int((g2_test.shape[1] - split) / int(split / 2))) if g2_test.shape[1] >= split else 1
g1_test = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.tile(g1_test, (1, amp2)), index=g2_test.index)
regroup_train = pd.concat([g1_train, g2_train], axis=1, join_axes=[g1_train.index])
regroup_train = numpy.transpose(regroup_train.as_matrix())

regroup_test = pd.concat([g1_test, g2_test], axis=1, join_axes=[g1_test.index])
regroup_test = numpy.transpose(regroup_test.as_matrix())

# create labels
split3 = g1_train.shape[1]
labels_train = numpy.zeros(shape=[len(regroup_train), 1])
labels_train[0:split3] = 1

split4 = g1_test.shape[1]
labels_test = numpy.zeros(shape=[len(regroup_test), 1])
labels_test[0:split4] = 1

# change all nan to 0
regroup_train = numpy.nan_to_num(regroup_train)
regroup_test = numpy.nan_to_num(regroup_test)
labels_train = numpy.nan_to_num(labels_train)
labels_test = numpy.nan_to_num(labels_test)

#######################################################################################################################
#####################################################NEURAL NETWORK####################################################
#######################################################################################################################

# define variables
trainingtimes = 1000

# create model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 54781])
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([54781, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
# define linear regression model, loss function
y = tf.nn.sigmoid((tf.matmul(x, w) + b))

# define correct training group
ytt = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

# define cross optimizer and cost function
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, ytt))

# train step
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.3).minimize(mse)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for i in range(trainingtimes):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: regroup_train, ytt: labels_train})
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(sess.run(mse, feed_dict={x: regroup_train, ytt: labels_train}))
```

Comment: Could you describe the architecture of your classifier? And also, please post a sample code showing what you're doing

Comment: Not a problem! I will include the code up there. Thank you

Comment: Done! Please take a look and let me know if anything is confusing. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, leaving aside all your preprocessing code that has nothing to do with tensorflow, you should really avoid implementing the neural network's layers by hand and instead rely on the [`tf.layers.*`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers) premade layers. You have a `dense` layer after your input placeholder, with `sigmoid` activation, that then ends up in a `MSE` computation. My suggestion is to rewrite the code in those terms and update it here as well

Comment: I see. Thank you! I dont know if it would be possible if you could give me an example of how to code with tf.layers*. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

A few key issues here. You're trying to define a 1-layer neural network, which sounds good for this problem. But your hidden layer is much larger than it should be. Experiment with smaller weight sizes. Try 128, 256, 512, numbers like this (powers of two are not required).

Also, your input dimensionality is quite high. I know someone working on a very similar gene expression problem for cancer with something like 60,000 gene expressions and 10,000 samples. She has used PCA to reduce the dimensionality of the data while maintaining ~90% of the variance (she experimented with different values and found this about optimal).

That improved the results. Neural networks can overfit, the PCA dimensionality reductions was beneficial. The 1-layer fully connected network also out performed Logstic Regression and XGA boost in her experiments.

A couple of other things that she's working on with this problem, which may also apply to you:

- Multi-task learning proved to improve the results. She originally had 4 different neural networks (4 outputs given the same data) when she combined them into 1 neural network with 4 loss functions it improved the results of all 4.
- Instead of PCA you can use auto-encoders as an alternative dimensionality reduction technique. It's entirely possible to connect an auto-encoder to this network and train it in conjunction with a loss function. I haven't actually experimented with this (yet) though, so I can only say that I expect it to improve the results in theory. The PCA approach will be quicker to test so I'd start there.

Comment: Wow thank you for all these suggestions. I have to look up a lot of the stuff you're talking about but I'll see what I can get out of them and hopefully get back to you! Thank you!!

Comment: I am wondering when you say use smaller weight sizes. Are you talking about shrinking my microarray data to some selected genes instead of using the entire dataset?

Comment: I'm actually talking about the hidden layer of a neural network. But I notice now that you're actually just doing a linear regression classifier. You don't have a hidden layer. Doing so would most likely help. Also, if you are doing a 0/1 classifier you'll get better results with cross entropy loss than square error (if it's regression square error is correct).  In any case, shrinking your input dimensionality is probably a reasonable place to start improving.

Comment: I'll look into that too! Thank you for your advices

Comment: Hi I am wondering. If I were to do PCA and use PCA dim1 and PCA dim 2 as my two axis. Would I only have two weights in that case?

Comment: As part of the PCA algorithm it will tell you how much variance it's keeping for a given dimensionality. Reducing it to two Dimensions would keep very little of the variance, and dramatically oversimplify the data. Your results would almost surely suffer. You want to find the lowest dimensionality that keeps more like 90 to 99% of your variance. But to answer your question directly, if you reduced it to two dimensions and still used linear regression then two weights is correct. If you add a hidden layer in there and use a neural network then the hidden layer could have any number of weights.

Comment: I see! Perfect. Thank you so much. I've been looking through the web alot to try to understand the implementation of hidden networks. Is it correct to assume my linear regression is my hidden network? Or what would you suggest for my case. Sorry to labor you with so many questions I am still a novice trying to learn. Thank you for your help.